# How can I open Jboss port 4447?

Tags: java, port, jboss6.x

I have a Jboss 6.1 server and I'd like to use remote EJB connection from a remote client.

But JBoss port 4447 is always closed, connection is refused.

How can I open this port?

Answer (score 2):

I assumed you are using Remote protocol to get JNDI resources in server from a Java program

By default, Remote port is not closed in JBOSS servers.

To access Remote protocol , you need to create an application user and use that credentials while connecting.

Find the `add-user.bat (for windows) / add-user.sh (for linux)` and create a application Realm user.

After that use that user name and password in your program.

For reference :[check this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Operations_Network/3.1/html/How_to_Manage_JBoss_Servers/eap6-management-users.html)

But here are other things to ensure:

Check your log for the below line:

```
[Server:ServiceNode-1] 19:40:39,323 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS017100: Listening on fedora18/localhost:4447
```

And ensure that no other programs uses the port 4447. (using netstat or something like that)

Comment: Thanks, but there is not add-user.sh in JBoss 6.1.

Comment: Use this URL to open jmx-console
[link]http://127.0.0.1:8080/jmx-console/ 
And start  Jboss-remoting ,After that you could access using port 4446